# how to add missing tlmgr

Tags: texlive-2021

I'm migrating from Scientific Linux 6.2 to Slackware Linux 15.0
Now I find that tlmgr is missing.
Not a path matter: I can't find the binary even using find.
To be sure, in
/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive
I find tlmgr.pl and tlmgrgui.pl
but no tlmgr binary.

Need help, thx.

Comment: a linux packaged tex under /usr/share should be managed by your linux package manager, `apt` or `yum` or whatever you use, `tlmgr` is the manager for upstream `texlive` installed (usually as `/usr/local/texlive<year>`) direct from TUG

Comment: @david-carlisle I have no /usr/local/texlive<year> directory. So I guess I'll do without tlmgr.